# Transform column index of dataframe to yearmon

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have the following data frame

```
data_frame <- data.frame(sku = c("A","B","C"), forecast1 = c(1,2,3), forecast2 = c(4,5,6), forecast3 = c(7,8,9))
```

I want to transform de column names to a sequence of dates with format **yearmon** and gather them with the following shape:

```
colnames(data_frame)[2:4] <- c("2020_03","2020_04","2020_05")
gather(data_frame,"yearmon","forecast",2:4)
```

I tried the following:

```
months <- list()
date_origin <- as.yearmon("2020-02")
for (i in 1:3){
  months[i] <- as.yearmon(months + i/12)
}
colnames(df_prevision)[c(2:84] <- months
df_prevision_gather <- gather(df_prevision,"month","forecast",2:4)
```

Comment: insteead of `months` as `list`, may be you need a `vector`, `months <- c(); Also, inside the loop, `months` is called for `as.yearmon` is an empty. list.  May be you need to call the colnames

Comment: Perhaps you need `months <- c(); nm1 <- names(data_frame)[-1];for(i in seq_along(nm1)) months[i] <- as.character(zoo::as.yearmon(nm1[i], "%Y_%m") + i/12)
> months
[1] "Apr 2020" "Jun 2020" "Aug 2020"`

Comment: Do you need `gather(data_frame,"yearmon","forecast",2:4) %>%
  mutate(yearmon = as.yearmon(yearmon, "%Y_%m"))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create column names of the form yyyy-mm, perform the `gather` and convert the column named `yearmon` using `as.yearmon`:

```
nc <- ncol(data_frame)
ym <- seq(as.yearmon("2020-03"), length = nc-1, by = 1/12)
names(data_frame)[-1] <- format(ym, "%Y-%m")

data_frame %>%
  gather("yearmon", "forecast", -1) %>%
  mutate(yearmon = as.yearmon(yearmon))
```

giving:

```
  sku  yearmon forecast
1   A Mar 2020        1
2   B Mar 2020        2
3   C Mar 2020        3
4   A Apr 2020        4
5   B Apr 2020        5
6   C Apr 2020        6
7   A May 2020        7
8   B May 2020        8
9   C May 2020        9
```